# How to drop cache for part of file?

Tags: linux, caching, operating-system, filesystems, dd

Assuming I have read a large file (10GB) to memory (with 32GB size) so the memory holds all the 10GB in page cache, and now I want to drop the first 1GB out of the cache but retain the others. Is it achievable under Linux?

I have tried dd introduced [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36907/drop-a-specific-file-from-the-linux-filesystem-cache) but it doesn't work, although it can drop cache for the whole file.

Comment: How are you reading the file? Memmap?

Comment: Does it matter? You can assume the file comes to OS page by mmap, or fread.

Comment: If you do fread, the entire file is not going to be cached.